# Get preview rowvalue filtered by ID

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've been struggling with DAX while creating a model to publish on Power BI and the actual problem is presented on the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kI2FL.png). Basically I need a column that shows the value from the predecessor time for the same id.

[image]

I did with ranking but wanted to know if it is possible to make it better.

How would you guys do it?

```
Rank = COUNTROWS(FILTER(test; [id] = EARLIER([id]) && [Date] <= EARLIER([Date])))
Past = if(test[Rank]=1;0; LOOKUPVALUE(test[qt];teste[Rank];test[Rank]-1;test[id];test[id]))
```

Comment: The may problem is that I have a 10,000,000 rows so the ranking takes TONS of time. :/

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution tested with the basic model you posted, I don't guarantee this is a machine low cost expression but you can give it a try.

I've created a column called PREVIOUS in which is calculated the previous `qty` for every row based on the date for the same `id`.

```
PREVIOUS =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( TableName[qt] ),
    FILTER (
        TableName,
        EARLIER ( TableName[id] ) = TableName[id]
            && EARLIER ( TableName[date] ) > TableName[date]
    )
)
```

The following is a Power BI table using the `PREVIOUS` column.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.